# SSRS 2012 - Explain input parameters before report loads

Tags: reporting-services

When a user hits my report I require they select a parameter to continue.  What I would like to do is explain to the user, before they have selected an option, a little about the parameter options.  It is fairly straight forward in the report below, however I have others that are much more complex.

Currently, the user has to select options then view the report; at which time an explanation of the parameters is available as part of the report.  To me, it seems silly that a user would have to pick something 'blindly' just to get an understanding of how that parameter will impact the results.

I realize that appropriate parameter naming goes a long way, and we do our best to make that happen.  We have a few situations where a sentence or two would go a long way in clarifying something before a user runs a report.

I have also used default parameters in the past to get the report to fully load when they first hit the page but that is not the solution I am looking for here.

Thanks in advance for your help!

[image: SSRSParamDesc]

Comment: You could check for the default parameter and display some help text in the report itself, but otherwise, Kyzen is right: there's no easy out of the box method to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible to do via any provided functionality.  The only way you're going to get this is if you use custom CSS sheets when accessing the report (either as a URL querystring parameter, or replacing the default stylesheets), or otherwise creating your own report page(s) to house your reports instead of Report Manager.

Comment: Thanks, I may explore that option if time permits.